# Oracle can only login as sysdba / can't login with configured user?

Tags: oracle

So I created the user w3038519 in the Oracle database configuration as I was installing Oracle yet it does not let me login with it.

```
C:\Users\Chris>sqlplus w13038519/mypass

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Fri Aug 14 00:26:16 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Could the account be locked somehow? Is there any way I can unlock it or create another user? The following doesn't work

```
sqlplus w13038519/mypass as sysdba
sqlplus osauthentication/anyuserpass as sysdba

SQL> create user chris
  2  identified by chrispass
  3  ;
create user chris
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

SQL> create user C##chris
  2  identified by chrispass
  3  ;
create user C##chris
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65048: error encountered when processing the current DDL statement in
pluggable database PDBORCL
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

I can't do anything I need to with sysdba because you can't create triggers logged in sysdba

I watched some tutorial and the person just setup sysdba as I have done and now can't use triggers.

I hate oracle so much. It's so retarded to use the most unideal platform there is

Comment: If it was locked it would tell you so upon your login attempt. Try to query `dba_users` and look for the created username and its account_status. Did you try to create C##chris when you were logged as sysdba?

Answer (score 1):

You have created a container database instead of a traditional one. In this case, When you use `/ as sysdba`, you connect to the root container, where you can not create reguler users, only common users (starting with `c##`), so your user `w13038519` can not exist in the root container. Run the below query:

```
select con_id from cdb_users where username = 'W13038519';

    CON_ID
----------
         3
```

This should return the container database where your user was created. If you get no result, your user does not exist. To find the name of the container:

```
SQL> select name from v$pdbs where con_id = 3;

NAME
------------------------------
PDB1
```

If you have a TNS entry pointing to that container database, you can connect as:

`sqlplus w13038519/september23@PDB1`

If you do not need the Multitenant Architechture specifically, you will save yourself a lot of trouble by creating a traditional database.

Comment: not sure about saving trouble, but just one less thing to learn...until this is the default and ONLY architecture in Oracle Database

Answer (score 0):

create user C##TESTDB identified by TESTDB container = all;
ORA-65048: error encountered when processing the current DDL statement in
pluggable database PDBORCL
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

in my case this worked

alter session set "_oracle_script"=true;

create user C##TESTDB identified by TESTDB;
user created;